# match entre 2 array de forma aleatoria, asignando una cantidad determinada de matchs por valor

Tags: php

tengo 2 arrays que son expositores y compradores, estos se seleccionan con select2 múltiple, ingreso por teclado la cantidad de citas que puede tener cada empresa(expositores/compradores), ejemplo si ingreso 2 cada expositor puede tener 2 citas con 2 compradores, lo mismo para los compradores pueden tener 2 citas con 2 expositores al azar, no encuentro la logica para resolver el problema

```
 <?php
    $expositores = ['google', 'microsoft', 'facebook', 'amazon'];
    $compradores = ['fernando', 'sebastian', 'juan', 'camilo'];
    $numero = 2;
    $leng = count($expositores);      
    
    for ($e = 0; $e < $leng; $e++) {
        $expositor = array_rand($expositores, 1);
        $nombre_expositor = $expositores[$expositor];
        $comprador = array_rand($compradores, $numero);
        // $nombre_comprador = $compradores[$comprador];
        foreach ($comprador as $value) {
            $nombre_comprador = $compradores[$value];
            $match = $nombre_expositor . '-' . $nombre_comprador;
            echo $match;
            echo '<br>';
        }
        unset($expositores[$expositor]);
        echo '<br>';
        echo '----------------------------------';
        echo '<br>';
    }

?>
```

este es el resultado que me da este codigo, no se repiten los expositores, pero si los compradores(mas de 2 repeticiones)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo hacer para evitar que los compradores se repitan mas de el numero de citas indicado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo, duplicar los elementos de cada array `n` veces para ir formando pares evitando duplicados, algo así:

```
<pre>
<?php
    $n=2;
    $exp = ['google', 'microsoft', 'facebook', 'amazon'];
    $cmp = ['fernando', 'sebastian', 'juan', 'camilo'];
    $expositores=[];
    $compradores=[];
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
        $expositores=array_merge($expositores,$exp);
        $compradores=array_merge($compradores,$cmp);
    }
    shuffle($expositores);
    shuffle($compradores);
    $citas=[];
    foreach($expositores as $i=>$e){
        while(in_array($e.'-'.$compradores[0],$citas))
            shuffle($compradores);
        $citas[]=$e.'-'.$compradores[0];
        unset($compradores[0]);
        shuffle($compradores);
    }       
    print_r($citas);
```

Seguro que se puede optimizar un poco, pero hace lo que comentas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios

Los duplicados los evito comprobando si un determinado par ya existe en el array con `in_array`. Mientras exista, barajo los que van quedando y vuelvo a comprobarlo.

Comment: sinceramente no entiendo bien como logra que no se repita, pero efectivamente funciona

Comment: Te amplío la respuesta. Fue lo que se me ocurrió en el momento, seguro que hay más formas :)